# How to configure Quasar SPA / Webpack dev server to launch in a subfolder for proxying with Apache?

Tags: webpack, quasar

I'd like the following dev setup:

- `http://mydevhost/` serving a regular PHP app
- `http://mydevhost/admin/` serving a Webpack dev server (Quasar SPA)

Now I've setup a proxy on Apache with this line in the vhost:

`ProxyPass "/admin/" "http://localhost:8080/"`

The proxy works but Webpack is unable to load the assets as it wants `http://mydevhost/app.js` instead of `http://mydevhost/admin/app.js`. I tried to configure `publicPath` and `filename` in `quasar.conf.js` to `/admin/` but without success (still looking for `/app.js`).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I found a way to solve this.

In Apache vhost, set up the proxy to the webpack dev server (serving at `http://localhost:8080`):

```bsh
ProxyPassMatch ^/admin(?!/api)(/.*)$ http://localhost:8080/admin$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/admin(?!/api)(/.*)$ http://localhost:8080/admin$1
ProxyPassMatch ^/((?:.*js)|(?:statics|sock-node|fonts|img)/.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/((?:.*js)|(?:statics|sock-node|fonts|img)/.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1
```

All routes starting with `/admin` will now be handled with VueRouter, except the one starting with `/admin/api`.

Then in VueRouter, set up all routes to start with `/admin`.

```js
const routes: RouteConfig[] = [
    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: () => import('layouts/DefaultLayout.vue'),
        children: [/* put other routes here */]
    }
];
```